# quad precision blas/lapack

Tags: c++, math, matrix, fortran

What is the best blas/lapack library for quad precision (128 bit floating point)?

I supposes that the reference fortran versions can be compiled as quad precision?

This library would need to be callable from both Fortran and C++.  I would be using this with the __float128 datatype from the gnu compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) linear algebra template library for C++.  It is pretty complete with regards to BLAS and LAPACK functions and the interfaces are much easier to use (in my opinion).

A word of warning:  You might quickly run into problems with the `__float128` datatype because fundamental operation like e.g. `log` are not implemented.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::Matrix<__float128,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> MatrixXf128;

int main() {
    MatrixXf128 m(2,2);
    m << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0;

    MatrixXf128 m2 = m * m;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did not want to rewrite my code, so I ended up compiling the blas/lapack routines I needed using gfortran with "-freal-8-real-16".  gfortran maps transcendentals to intrinsic functions.  The boost float128 header maps these functions similar to their double counterparts.